# How to create a common function in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I want to create a common functionality in Moodle. That function will be accessible to all the pages like login, course etc. So, in which file or lib, I need to write the function and how will I access it? My function name will be like:

```
function addpoints() {
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What is is that you want to do with the function?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a local plugin to hold functions like that. You will then need to call:
require_once($CFG->direct.'/local/mylocalplugin/lib.php');
addpoints();

If you are using moodle 2.6 or above, you can make use of the automatic class loading feature ( http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Automatic_class_loading ) to load your code without the require_once line, but that is a bit more fiddly to set up.